# How would I make the back of this chair?

Tags: mesh, objects

I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how to create the back and bottom part of this chair (not the legs, just the outline of the chair). I thought about doing some extruding from creating the bottom but then I got very confused on how to create the circular backing and its seams. I'm still learning each day and this chair might be too advanced for where I am I guess but any pointers would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can begin with a 60 vertex cylinder, make an inset:

[image]

Extrude a quarter of the border faces:

[image]

Move up some vertices to make the bumps:

[image]

Push a bit back the whole top:

[image]

Create some edge loops to round the shape and to prepare the seams:

[image]

Select all and make a *Mesh > Symmetrize*:

[image]

Some additional edge loops:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is so helpful! Thanks so much! If I wanted to make the last two bumps on either side ends more curved out (like in the photo) would you know how to then make that happen? Would I just need to add some loop cuts and extend them manually? I hope I'm making sense!

Comment: I've edited my answer, yes add some edge loops, the back will be a bit tricky but don't hesitate to create separate meshes as there are seams you don't have to make it with one unique mesh

Comment: thanks for clarifying! I'm going to try and practice it a bit more as mine isn't turning out like how yours is, I think I'm just stuck on the back getting disfigured and some other things. I really appreciate your help!